# Deploy VS 2010 database project using MSBuild and TeamCity

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild, teamcity, database-project

Is it possible to deploy a VS 2010 database project using TeamCity?

I am building my whole solution, and deploying a website to my server, this all works fine.

The final step I want to trigger is the deploy of the database project which generates a sql script and deploys it.

I have the "Create a deployment script (.sql) and deploy to the database" option selected as a deploy action, my Configuration target is set to build and deploy the database project, but I just can't figure how to get TeamCity and MSBuild to trigger it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since my question got upvoted today, I'm revisiting with the answer I found.

I did the following:

- created a Deploy step in my build
- pointed it at my VS database project (.dbroj file)
- enetered command line params as follows: /t:Deploy /p:TargetDatabase=MyDBName /P:Configuration=%env.Configuration%

**Edit 16/11/12**: Another upvote, so revisiting again. Since I posted this, things became a bit clearer. I was originally running TeamCity on my dev PC.

When I came to move it onto a server, the only way I could get the database deploy to work was to install Visual Studio on the server which is a pain.

Comment: If it's a SSDT project you're deploying, you should only need DacFX installed, as sqlpackage.exe is included there. I haven't tried it, but should work.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/05/03/sql-server-data-tier-application-framework-may-2013-available.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ssdtblog+%28SQL+Server+Developer+Tools+Team+Blog%29

Comment: @Trondh no, it was a VS 2010 database project

Answer (score 16):

Visual Studio must be installed for this to work.

For the **original SQL Server 2005/2008 Database Project types**:

1. Create a build step of runner type Visual Studio to build the solution.
2. Create a build step of runner type Command Line. Set Command Executable to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Deploy\VSDBCMD.exe`. Set Command Parameters to `/a:Deploy /dd:+ /manifest:%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\<PROJECT PATH>\sql\debug\<PROJECT NAME>.deploymanifest`. (See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for VSDBCMD.exe parameters).

For the SQL Server Database Project provided by **SQL Server Data Tools** or **Visual Studio 2012/2013**:

1. Create a build step of runner type Visual Studio to build the solution.
2. Create a build step of runner type Command Line. Set Command Executable to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools\sqlpackage.exe`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) for sqlpackage.exe parameters. Here's an example with the deployment settings stored in an XML file (created via the Publish option): `/Action:Publish /SourceFile:%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\<PROJECT PATH>\bin\Debug\<PROJECT NAME>.dacpac /Profile:%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\<PATH TO PROJECT>\PublishSettings.xml`.